# Printing form in ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, forms, printing

I have a form with two buttons in ASPX page. One to print with the user input and the other to print empty form. I used 'window.print()' event to print form with user input. How can i print the empty form, even though if user has entered something in the form when user clicks on other print button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you generate an html for blank form - (you can use different page or use the same ASPX page) and open it in a different window and issue window.print() within.

If you don't want to open new window then open the page in `iframe` and issue `window.print()` for iframe. If you don't want this to be visible then keep the iframe size as 1x1 px or position the iframe (or container div) in negative left/top coordinates.